# Is a uniquely geodesic space contractible? I

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, metric-geometry, geodesic

> Is a [uniquely geodesic space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#U) [contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) ?

We assume in addition that closed metric balls are compact.

A post without this extra assumption is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480461/is-a-uniquely-geodesic-space-contractible-ii).

Comment: Do you also want to assume that closed metric balls are compact?

Comment: No, I do not have an example, but I think it would be easier to prove under this extra assumption.

Comment: OK, I will try.

Comment: @studiosus : I edit the extra assumption, you can remove your comments and improve your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume in addition that closed metric balls in your metric space $X$ are compact (I do not know what to say in general). I will use the notation $g(p,q)$ for the unique geodesic in $X$ connecting $p$ to $q$ and regarded as a map from 
an interval $[0,D]$ to $X$, where $D$ is the distance from $p$ to $q$.

Pick a point $x_0\in X$ and define a family of maps $f_s: X\to X$ by  $f_s(x)$ defined to be the point on the geodesic $g(x_0, x)$ so that the distance from $x_0$ to $f_s(x)$ is $s$ times the distance from $x_0$ to $x$. Clearly, $f_1(x)=x$, $f_0(x)=x_0$ for all $x\in X$. What is not clear is if the map is continuous. I think, it would follow from continuity of the map sending $x$ to the geodesic $g(x_0, x)$ (where I use  topology of uniform convergence on the set of geodesics). Suppose that I have a sequence $x_n\in X$ convergent to $x\in X$. I claim that such sequence always contains a subsequence so that the corresponding sequence of geodesics converges to $g$.

By the compactness assumption I made and the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, the sequence of geodesics $g_n$ (regarded as maps of course) converges (after passing to a subsequence) to a geodesic $g'$ connecting $x_0$ to $x$. (Usually the A-A theorem is applied to maps with a fixed domain. In our case, the sequence of domains is a sequence of intervals $[0, D_n]$ where $D_n$ is the distance form $x_0$ to $x_n$. To resolve this issue, take some $D\ge D_n, \forall n,$ and extend the maps $g_n$ to $[0,D]$ by constant maps on intervals $[D_n,D]$.)

Since $X$ is uniquely geodesic, $g'=g$. Hence, our subsequence in $g_n$ converges to $g$.  Now, use the fact that in a compact metric space $G$ (the space of suitable geodesics in our case), a sequence $g_n$ converges to $g$ if and only if every convergent subsequence in $(g_n)$ converges to $g$. Thus, we proved that the sequence of geodesics $(g_n)$ converges to $g$ and, hence, the map from $X$ to the space of geodesics is continuous.

Comment: How do you get assumptions of A-A from the properness of the space? Don't you use some kind of continuity here?

Comment: @savick01: AA theorem has two assumptions: 1. Compactness of the target space (holds by the hypothesis). 2. Equicontinuity of the family of maps. My maps are (essentially) isometries (more precisely, they are distance non-increasing maps), so in the definition of equicontinuity you take $\delta$ equal to $\epsilon$. If it is not sufficiently clear I will make an edit in my answer.

Comment: @studiosus : could you also explain (in edit) what kind of theorems you might need for a generalization without this extra assumption ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: I have absolutely no idea, since A-A theorem fails (even for sequences of geodesics contained in a complete metric ball) without local compactness. My personal feeling is that you just have to restrict the discussion to locally compact metric spaces.

Comment: @studiosus : unfortunately, a part of my needs use non-"locally compact" space.  A-A theorem fails without local compactness, right, but maybe what you need (which is more restrictive than A-A theorem itself) could be generalized. What do you think ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: As I said, A-A theorem fails for sequences of geodesics in a closed bounded subset (consider the closed unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space); hence, everything that I know fails and I cannot help you here.

Comment: @studiosus: Now it's perfectly clear, thanks.