# Is a uniquely geodesic space contractible? II

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, geodesic

> Is a [uniquely geodesic space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#U), [contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) ?

With the extra assumption that closed metric balls are compact, there is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479022/is-a-uniquely-geodesic-space-contractible).

We expect here an answer beyond this extra assumption (justifying [functional-analysis](/questions/tagged/functional-analysis)).

Comment: A uniquely geodesic space where geodesics vary continuously with endpoints is contractible. (Pick a point, and use geodesics to that point as contracting map.)

Comment: @user68316 : Thank you ! Is the converse true ?  (I don't know, but 'a priori' no). Do you know a counter-example ?

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true. Look at the closed upper hemisphere of the 2 sphere. It is homeomorphic to a disk and this contractible. However, there are many geodesics between the two poles (for example the two different directions around the equator).