# On continuously uniquely geodesic space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, geodesic

This question was inspired by [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480461/is-a-uniquely-geodesic-space-contractible-ii#comment1036328_480461) of [@68316](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/68316/user68316).

**Definition** : A continuously uniquely geodesic space is a [uniquely geodesic space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#U) whose geodesics vary continuously with endpoints.

> **Question** : Is there a uniquely geodesic space which is not continuously uniquely geodesic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this example in the book, (exercise) example of a complete unique 
geodesic space which is not locally compact.
               [Complete unique geodesic space but not proper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652902/complete-unique-geodesic-space-but-not-proper)

Comment: Could you give me the reference of the book and the page on which is written this example?

Comment: Sure Metric space of Non positive curvature by Martin R.bridson and Andre Haefliger. Its appear in page 38 ex3.14 , I feel bit uncomfortable with the example construction joing $\alpha_n$ by isometry, if you get the picture please tell me also I guess at point $\pi$ it is not locally compact? and the geodesic does not continuously converge to line joining 0,\pi?

Comment: I have ecopy of the book let me know if you need it

Comment: It's ok, I've found it [here](http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/rigidity/bh.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

**Update: This example is wrong, please check below comment from @Anton Petrunin**

One example is the following, but there might be simpler ones:

Consider the set 
$$X = \{(r\cos t,r \sin t) \in \mathbb R^2 | 0 \leq r \leq 1,\ 0 < t \leq \pi/4\} \cup \{(x,0) | -1 \leq x \leq 0\} \cup \{(1,0)\}$$ equipped with the intrinsic metric induced from the standard metric of $\mathbb R^2$, i.e. the distance between points is the infimum of lengths of curves connecting them and lying in $X$. This is not a uniquely geodesic space since there is no geodesic connecting points $(x,0)$ and $(1,0)$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 0$. But if one identifies the points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ the quotient space, equipped with the quotient metic, is a uniquely geodesic space, say $Y$.

However $Y$ is not continous: Consider the sequence $v_n = (\cos \frac 1 n, \sin \frac 1 n)$. Then $v_n \to (1,0)$ but the geodesics $\gamma_n$ connecting $(0,0)$ and $v_n$ do not converge to the geodesic connecting $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, which is given by the segment $t \mapsto (-t,0)$, $t \in [0,1]$.

It is worth mentioning that $Y$ is not complete as a metric space. Finding complete examples is probably harder, if there are any. My guess would be that a complete uniquely geodesic space is in fact continous.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice counter-example ! See [this specialization](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482311/on-continuously-uniquely-geodesic-space-ii).

Comment: In fact $Y$ is *not* uniquely geodesic --- look at the points $(-\tfrac12,0)$ and $(\tfrac12,\varepsilon)$. I have another construction here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355887/