# Complete unique geodesic space but not proper

Tags: general-topology

Please comment on the example below about a complete unique geodesic space 
but which is not proper :
   Let $Y_n$ be  the subspace of $S^2$ obtained by taking a sector bounded by two 
arcs of great circles, each of length $\pi$, which meet in north and south pole,
at an angle $\pi/4$, and then removing a open ball of radius $1/n$ about the north
pole . $Y_n$ with the induced metric is a topological disc whose boundary consist 
of three unique geodesic segments, two of which have length $\pi-1/n$. Let X be the space obtained by taking the interval $[0,\pi]$ and for every n>2 attaching 
$Y_n$ to the initial segment $[0,\pi]$ by of the side of length $\pi-1/n$.
   [image]description here

Comment: Show me why this space does not vary continuously with their end points ? That is to if x,y are two points and x_n tend to x , y_n tend to y then geodesic joining x_n,y_n tend to geodesic joining x,y