# Does convexity implies contractibility in length space?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, metric-geometry

It is known that convexity implies contractibility in Euclidean spaces. I want to know whether it holds in a general length space. To be specific:

Let $(X,d)$ be a length space and $A\subseteq X$. $A$ is said to be [convex](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Convexity) if for any $x,y\in A$, there is a shortest curve in $A$ joining $x,y$. Is $A$ contractible or not?

The question arises when I am reading a classical paper by [S. Alexander and R. Bishop](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285344014_The_Hadamard-Cartan_theorem_in_locally_convex_metric_spaces). In this paper, convexity is defined as follows: $A$ is called convex if for any two scaled geodesics $\alpha,\beta:[0,1]\to A$ the function $d(\alpha(t),\beta(t))$ is convex. This is a condition similar but wearker than having nonpositive curvature. An argument in section 3 shows that such convex sets are contractible. However, this kind of convexity seems so 'strong' that I cannot come up with an example other than geodesic spaces with nonpositive curvature.

Thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: What is a "length space"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $(Y, d)$ is a length space iff, for all $r>0$ and all $x,y \in Y$, there exists a finite set of points $x_1,\ldots,x_k \in Y$ such that $x_1=x,\ x_k=y,\ d(x_i,x_{i+1})\leq r$ for each $i$, and $\sum^k_{ i = 1} d(x_i,x_{i+1})<d(x,y)+r$ -- I think it's connected to rectifiability.  Burago's book on Metric Geometry, if you have it to hand, seems to a be a standard reference

Comment: Great. It seems like $\sum d(x_i,x_{x+1})<d(x,y)+r-1$ must be a typo; this imequality implies that $d(x,y)<0$ for some $x$  and $y$. (You diidn't say what $d$ was; I'm assuming it's a metric...)

Comment: A more interesting question is if a uniquely geodesic metric space is contractible (uniquely geodesic means that any two points are connected by a geodesic and this geodesic is unique). This was asked earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480461/is-a-uniquely-geodesic-space-contractible-ii?noredirect=1&lq=1) and is still open afaik.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Thanks! The reference is very helpful.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I didn't write $d(x,y)-r-1$ actually!  That $-1$ is $--$ (em dash) followed by $I$, for "I think..."  Sorry for the confusion, but you seem to have solved the problem even with my unhelpfulness

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense..

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm still not sure what a length space is; there is at least one major problem with the definition given in a comment above. But, trying to extract the spirit of the problematic definition:

Say $S=\:z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$, and define a metric on $S$ by saying $$d(e^{it},e^{i(t+\delta)})=|\delta|$$**if** $|\delta|\le\pi$. Is $(S,d)$ a length space? It's certainly not contractible.

Comment: Yup, that's a length space (by any definition), its convex (by the OP's definition), and it's not contractible.